# MongoDB: Select specific subdocuments

Tags: php, mongodb

this is an example for a document in the products collection.

```
object(MongoId)#8 (1) {
  ["$id"]=>
  string(24) "5165b2c8ac951ab812000001"
}
int(0)
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sValue"]=>
    string(10) "1223828372"
    ["iPosX"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sValue"]=>
    string(12) "Epson EB-S11"
    ["iPosX"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sValue"]=>
    string(6) "Beamer"
    ["iPosX"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sValue"]=>
    string(48) "TV>>Beamer & Projektoren|Epson EB-S11-1300742000"
    ["iPosX"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sValue"]=>
    string(6) "398.00"
    ["iPosX"]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sValue"]=>
    string(85) "http://www.myshop.com/product-1223828372.html"
    ["iPosX"]=>
    int(5)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sValue"]=>
    string(5) "Epson"
    ["iPosX"]=>
    int(6)
  }
}
```

I want to select the products in this collection, but not all of the subdocuments. For example: I just want to get the subdocuments where the iPosX is 1, 2 or 4 from this document.

To be specific: I need all information from this products plus the subdocuments where the iPosX Field is 1, 2 or 4.

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance.
Max

Answer (score 1):

Your best approach is to use the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/) in MongoDB 2.2+:

```
db.products.aggregate(
    // Optional: could include a $match to limit the matching documents

    // Create a stream of documents from the products array
    { $unwind: "$products" },

    // Filter the matching products
    { $match: {
        "products.iPosX": { $in: [1,2,4] }
    }},

    // Reshape output so matched products are at top level of results
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        sValue: "$products.sValue",
        iPosX:  "$products.iPosX",
    }}
)
```

Example output:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "sValue" : "Epson EB-S11",
            "iPosX" : 1
        },
        {
            "sValue" : "Beamer",
            "iPosX" : 2
        },
        {
            "sValue" : "398.00",
            "iPosX" : 4
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: You may also want to vote/watch the feature request [SERVER-6612](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6612) in the MongoDB Jira issue tracker.  This feature suggestion is to support projecting multiple array values using a projection specifier in a normal `find()` query (eg similar to `$elemMatch`, but returning all matching elements instead of only the first one found).