# Mongoose 3.6: Returning one subdocument by id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of threads which each have a nested array of comment documents.
I want to return just one comment document based on its id.
I have the thread id and the comment id.
Alas I can not seem to do it - searching around I have come up with the following but I get an error.

> { [MongoError: Unsupported projection option: $elemMatch] name: 'MongoError' }

This seems like a very typical use case, can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

```
       var thread_id =  vo.thread_id;
       var _id =  vo._id;
       threads.model.find({_id:thread_id}).select({ comments: { $elemMatch: {_id:_id}}}).exec(function (err, thread) {
                    console.log("***************************************");
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log(thread);
                    done();
                });
```

Comment: On further research it would seem the install of mongo db I am running on is 1.6.2, $elemMatch was introduced in ver 2.2. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB extract only the selected item in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/mongodb-extract-only-the-selected-item-in-array)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, MongoDB (and hence Mongoose) doesn't directly support that operation currently. MongoDB doesn't have the ability to return just one element of an array, so Mongoose doesn't support that either. (If though you happened to have the index of the array item, you could use `slice` ([documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/slice/#slice-projection))).

Further, the `select` function only takes a list of fields you want to include/exclude ([documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select)). The `select` function maps to the [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#projections) functionality of MongoDB. It cannot use MongoDB operators.

You could do `select('comments') for example to only include the comments field from the document. But, this would return the entire array of`comments`. You would need to do client side filtering to extract the specific comment you're looking for.

There's an open request to add functionality to be able to extra a specific element from an array [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6612).

Some might suggest you try the Aggregation Framework ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15987719/95190)).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look.　Looks like it may be possible https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/3640687  however my version of mongodb is too old.